migrating node-sass to dart sass in react app and getting compilation error from react-dates package (da)
I am trying to migrate from node-sass to dart sass. I am also using react-dates package and including datePicker css file.
color: darken(#cacccd,10%); function is being used in datePicker and I am getting compilation error.

webpack rule config:
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const flexbugfixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes');
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: [devMode && 'react-refresh/babel'].filter(Boolean)
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: [autoprefixer, flexbugfixes]
            },
            sourceMap: true
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

how can I fix this error?
